# Making sense of "schon wieder"

Tags: translation

I cannot make sense of the *schon wieder* in the excerpt below.

> In der Redensart „Chapeau!“ beziehungsweise „Hut ab!“ ist diese Geste des Respekts erhalten. Auch das konkrete „Den-Hut-Ziehen“ gibt es noch. Unter Hutträgern. Aber wer trägt heute noch Hut? Diese bürgerliche Begrüßungsgeste blickt zwar auf ein relativ junges Alter zurück, ist jedoch **schon wieder** im Aussterben begriffen.

The last sentence seems to be saying that a particular gesture is in the process of becoming extinct *again*.  Why the "again"?  (FWIW, no earlier disappearance of the gesture is discussed anywhere before in the original source.)

Does *schon wieder* have a translation other than *again*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in this specific context *schon wieder* can also be translated as *already*. The excerpt states that the salutation of taking off one's hat is relatively young, but it is already disappearing from society.

Comment: The repetition *wieder* states here is the cycle of birth and death of that trend. *Schon* states its death came somewhat early.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is given in the very same sentence:

> Diese bürgerliche Begrüßungsgeste blickt zwar auf ein relativ junges Alter zurück...

Translates to:

> this civil gesture of greeting locks back on a relatively young age..

So: the gesture (taking the hat of) is not very old (it does not state how old exactly), but already is becoming forgotten.